# How do I call a particular function in javascript only when the whole browser is killed/closed?

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
    logout();
});
```

I want the `logout()` function to be called, only when the user closes the browser itself. But instead, in my code, even if I switch to another tab, the `logout()` function gets called. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't. When it's killed, it's simply gone.